# XSD - define type with parameter

Tags: xsd

Is it possible to define parameter for a type ? I want to have type that represents fixed length string but I dont want do define multiple such types for different lengths, that is `TFixedString(N)` so I could use `TFixedString(2)` and `TFixedString(16)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not do this.  It is not supported in XSD.